# "Embedly" didn't fully generated the facebook photo post

Tags: json, facebook, embedly

is anyone tried to integrate a facebook post / photo with embedly?

I try to copy post / photo url from facebook:
Post URL:
Showing full article same as using "Embed post" from facebook.
Photo URL: 
Showing only the exactly images, but not generated "title" and "description" parameter.

How can we accomplish this, is there any way to change parameter default value?

Thank you very much

Comment: your question is a bit confusing, eleborate a bit and maybe i will be able to help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use either facebook [Embedded Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts)   ,  Or you can use facebook SDK to get data from facebook.

Ofcourse Url to Image will embedd only image. And Url to complete post will embedd complete post.

Comment: I see, thank you @Salman Aslam. Yeah, when I use the image post url, embedly only result as an image, without fetching the full article data e.g: title, description. Hopefully in the future, we can customize how image post can appear, either to show post detail or hide it.

Comment: Although you can use graph api to get these elements and manipulate them by yourself.